# jQuery - Display message if array.filter fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, array-filter

I'm making a jQuery console and I'm using an array filled with the available commands to validate the user's input--so, for example, if they enter `help`, if `help` is in `array.name`, then continue to the next bit of code.

The problem is that I want to display a message such as "that command does not exist" when the `filter` fails entirely, as in `help` is not in the array at all. Here is my code so far:

```
var commands = [
    {   'name': 'help',
        'desc': 'display information about all available commands or a singular command',
        'args': 'command-name' },
    {   'name': 'info',
        'desc': 'display information about this console and its purpose' },
    {   'name': 'authinfo',
        'desc': 'display information about me, the creator' },
    {   'name': 'clear',
        'desc': 'clear the console' },
    {   'name': 'opensite',
        'desc': 'open a website',
        'args': 'url' },
    {   'name': 'calc',
        'desc': 'calculate math equations',
        'args': 'math-equation' },
    {   'name': 'instr',
        'desc': 'instructions for using the console' }
];

function detect(cmd) { // function takes the value of an <input> on the page
    var cmd = cmd.toLowerCase(); // just in case they typed the command in caps (I'm lazy)

    commands.filter(function(command) {
        if(command.name == cmd) {
            switch(cmd) {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("That command was not found."); // this fires every time command.name != cmd
        }
    }
}
```

I have a jsFiddle with (almost) all the code if need be.

http://jsfiddle.net/abluescarab/dga9D/

The else statement fires every time the command name isn't found--which is a lot, since it's looping through the array.

Is there a way to display a message if the command name is not found anywhere in the array while using `filter`?

Thanks in advance, apologies if I didn't make sense and for the wall of code, and I am open to suggestions of alternative ways to do this.

Comment: Could you use a boolean to flag if it's not found? So in your else statement instead of the alert put like "notFound = true;", then when your loop finishes just check if(notFound) { //do stuff } so your error only fires once.

Comment: @zgood Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try that right now and get back to you.

Comment: @zgood The array is still looped through to the end regardless of whether the value is found or not. I used "return" in an attempt to stop the loop, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_command(command_name) {

    var results = {};
    for (var key in commands) (function(name, desc, command) {

        if (name == command_name) (function() {

            results = command;
        }());

    }(commands[key]["name"], commands[key]["desc"], commands[key]));

    return (results);
};

get_command("help");
```

and not switch is try filter method function:

```
commands.filter = (function(command, success_callback, fail_callback) {

    if (get_command(command)["name"]) (function() {

       success_callback();
    }());

    else (function() {


        fail_callback();
    }());
});


commands.filter("help", function() {

    console.log("enter help command source :)");
}, function() {

    console.log("hey help command???");
});
```

take it easy.

Comment: Thanks! That works great! I can't decipher it, but it works great. Do I just check if get_command()['name'] returns undefined?

Comment: use commands.filter(command, success_callback, fail_callback) ok?